# Get version number from file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have file index.html where in first line I have build version like this:

```
<!-- [AIV]  Build version: 1.0.1 - Friday, January 5th, 2018, 2:16:09 PM  -->
```

I'd like to do this using windows .bat script. I tried:

```
findstr /r "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" index.html
```

but it doesn't work for me. Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: can you define "doesnt work"?

Comment: doesn't return any value

Comment: Did you not think, after it was unsuccessful to enter `FindStr /?` at the Command prompt?

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: @Jan, the text from `FindStr /?`, when read, explains how to use the poor regular expression implementation. What you've used above does not appear within the text displayed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the layout and structure of that first line remains consistent then the following, which uses variable expansion and replacement techniques, may prove helpful to you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "version="<"index.html"
Set "version=%version:*version:=%"
Set "version=%version: =%"
Set "version=%version:-="&:"%"
Echo [%version%]
Pause
```

Comment: In my file only version number and date is changing so I can use your script. Thank you!